# Externalising property files in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

How could I access external property files in my project just like other resources kept in the resource folder? Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

You have several ways to do it. One that occurs to me is that you do it using the context: property-placeholder tag of spring-context. I give you an example of how to do it in the typical spring configuration xml file:

1. Add the corresponding namespace:

> xmlns: context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

2. Add the context: property-placeholder tag pointing to your properties file: `<context: property-placeholder location = "classpath *: yourpropertiesfile.properties" />`
3. You use the properties it contains in those classes or places where you need it. For example in the same spring configuration XML file or as a property of a bean:

[Point 3 example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dbs4v.png)

Many more examples here: https://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring